# How can I install custom fonts when using a virtual environment in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I've created a virtaul enviroment for a project. I wanted to use google fonts (roboto). I installed on my mac but when trying to import the font, matplotlib does not find it. I tried to copy and paste the .ttf files into the fonts folder of matplotlib of my virtual enviroment but it didn't work. Any ideas?

I'm using vscode

even thought the .tff files are in the folder, when using:
`matplotlib.font_manager.findfont("RobotoCondensed.tft")`

I got:
findfont: Font family ['RobotoCondensed.tft'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans.

Comment: Is this just a typo on your part where you should have "RobotoCondensed.ttf" rather than "RobotoCondensed.tft"?

Comment: Also, check out https://scentellegher.github.io/visualization/2018/05/02/custom-fonts-matplotlib.html, in particular the last part where it adds in the font after finding the file.

Comment: @MattPitkin Thank you! Apparently the name of the font is "Roboto Condense" without any file extension (which I misspelled). I also tried adding the file path as the example from scentellegher and it also worked.